# Changing Maven Compiler plugin version to 1.6 gives error

Tags: build, maven-plugin

I get this error when I change the plugin version to be used as 1.6 instead of 1.5:

unmappable character for encoding UTF8

The character it try to map is the Copyright symbol.
My pom looks like this:

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must save your .java file with the symbol as UTF-8 encoded. Also add

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

into `<project>` and make the java encoding explicit:

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But, the issue is that, there is a lot of legacy code in the project and changing / saving all the java files in UTF-8 might not be possible at all.

Comment: It's required only for files which have non-ascii symbols. Usually it's not so much. As an option, you could set another encoding, not sure which one do you have. But it's very bad practice to use something other than utf or ascii (you could put your copyright symbol as `"\u00A9"`.